# Android reference devices for responsive webdesign

Tags: android, responsive-design, tablet, smartphone

Which devices (smartphone and tablet) do you recommend to buy as reference?
And what version of Android do you prefer?
Main goal: testing responsive websites in our small web studio.

Smartphones:

- Samsung Galaxy — S2, S3, S4 (but S4 and S3 seem to be too expensive).
- Google Nexus 4.
- 4.0 — 4.5 branded devices in middle cost segment.
- bi-brands or Chinese devices (low cost, Android 4.1+).

Tablets (I think, only 9.7/10.1 inches not 7 inches):

- Samsung (dunno which).
- Chinese devices.

We have limited resources, so…

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Google Reference Devices, as they always go through all Android versions, and they have always the latest version available. Right now they are:

- Nexus 7 (2012 and 2013 versions). 2012 version is the most sold Android Tablet. also works as a reference Portrait Tablet.
- Nexus 4
- Nexus 10. Reference Landscape Tablet.
- Nexus One or Nexus S for a reference Android Gingerbread device.

Then, if you have the budget, I would go for typical best sellers in all ranges:

- Galaxy S2, S3 and S4
- Galaxy Y, Ace, HTC Desire X
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 7, 8.9 and 10.